# Why does http put work, but http post does not?

Tags: angularjs

I have tested all web apis in post man and they all work fine

In my angular js code the http put works, I can edit existing records

The http post is pretty much identical, but every time I submit the server side comes back with a null

I also output all the object properties to the console when testing and they all write to console fine as well :

```
CreateController.Save function fired!!!
WebMarkService.js:30 Create Service fired!!!
WebMarkService.js:31 Name is test!!!
WebMarkService.js:32 Label is test!!!
WebMarkService.js:33 NavigateUrl is test!!!
WebMarkService.js:34 WebMark is [object Object]!!!
angular.js:10695 POST http://localhost:29830/api/WebMarks/[object%20Object] net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10695sendReq @ angular.js:10514status.$get.serverRequest @ angular.js:10221processQueue @ angular.js:14678(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14694parent.$get.Scope.$eval @ angular.js:15922parent.$get.Scope.$digest @ angular.js:15733parent.$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16030(anonymous function) @ angular.js:23486x.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5x.event.add.y.handle @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
WebMarkCreateController.js:37 -1
```

I have it in debugger in visual studio, so I can see why the connection is refused.

I am just wondering if there's something I Need to to for http post that I can skip for http put?

This should be so simple, but it's coming in null and it's driving me crazy!!! lol

```
//=============================================================================
// PUT: api/WebMarks/5
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult PutWebMark( int id, WebMark webMark )
//=============================================================================

//=============================================================================
// POST: api/WebMarks
[ResponseType( typeof( WebMark ) )]
public IHttpActionResult PostWebMark( WebMark webMark )
//=============================================================================

---------------------------------------------------------------

// add a service to the application module

(
function( app ) 
    {
    var WebMarkService = function( $http, webMarksApiUrl )
        {
        var getAll = function ()
            {
            return $http.get( webMarksApiUrl + "WebMarks/" );
            };

    var getById = function( id )
        {
        return $http.get( webMarksApiUrl + "WebMarks/" + id );
        };

    var update = function( webMark )//<-- works
        {
        console.log( "Update Service fired!!!" );
        console.log( "Name is " + webMark.WebMarkName + "!!!" );

        $http.defaults.headers.put[ "Content-Type" ] = "application/json"; // WORKING
        return $http.put( webMarksApiUrl + "WebMarks/" + webMark.WebMarkID, webMark );
        };

    var create = function( webMark ) //<-- does not work???
        {
        console.log( "Create Service fired!!!" );
        console.log( "Name is " + webMark.WebMarkName + "!!!" );
        console.log( "Label is " + webMark.WebMarkLabel + "!!!" );
        console.log( "NavigateUrl is " + webMark.WebMarkNavigateUrl + "!!!" );
        console.log( "WebMark is " + webMark + "!!!" );

        $http.defaults.headers.post[ "Content-Type" ] = "application/json"; //NOT WORKING
        return $http.post( webMarksApiUrl + "WebMarks/" + webMark );
        };

    var destroy = function( webMark )
        {
        console.log( "Destroy Service fired!!!" );
        console.log( "Name is " + webMark.WebMarkName + "!!!" );

        webMark.WebMarkIsDeleted = true;

        return $http.delete( webMarksApiUrl + "WebMarks/" + webMark.WebMarkID, webMark );
        };

    return { getAll: getAll, getById: getById, update: update, create: create, delete: destroy };
    };

    app.factory( "WebMarkService", WebMarkService );
    } ( angular.module( "MyWebMarks" ) ) 
)
```

//===========================================================================

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes( RouteCollection routes )
    {
    routes.IgnoreRoute( "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}" );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: there is no data argument in your `$http.post()` and you are trying to concatenate object `webMark` to string url

Comment: ... What @charlietfl said. Nutshell: "All these other things work except for the thing where I'm doing it differently."

Comment: how do I properly submit the webMark object to http. post then?  This works for the http.put which is almost identical

Comment: the same way you are doing it with `put` or `delete`. There would be no ID so change `+` to `,`

Comment: "Almost identical"... Well, not identical enough, I guess?

Comment: That's what i am doing now.  The parms for put are two  : id and webMark.  The parms for post are just one : webMark.  So how do I write the httppost?  $http.post( webMarksApiUrl + "WebMarks/" );    // ???

Comment: I got it.I have to include the id field even though the object has no id yet.  The http post method wants two parms, even though I have only declared one.  When I use $http.post( webMarksApiUrl + "WebMarks/" + webMark.WebMarkID, webMark )  it works just fine.  This makes no sense to me because the signature of the http post method is just one parm, but whatever.  It is working at least lol

Comment: It is bugging me why this works when I include the extra parm.   Do I need to update my route config? I will add that to my post